# bootstrap list button right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, list, css

Hello I have list in bootstrap:

```
<h4><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2</h4>
    <ul id="filter-version" class="filter multiple-select term-list">
        <li data-id="3">
            <a href="#">a</a>
        </li>
        <li data-id="1">
            <a href="#">b</a>
        </li>
        <li data-id="2">
            <a href="#">c</a>
        </li>
    </ul><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm more-less">Więcej</button>

    <span class="btn btn-default btn-sm start-filter" data-filter="version">Pokaż</span>
```

How can i align properly "Więcej" and "Pokaż" to the right? If i use float: right then the buttons are in same line as "1,2,3,4".

Thanks.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/C2K9Z/156/
```

Comment: use pull-right in your button class

Comment: doesnt work, button is on same line as li

Comment: do you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/C2K9Z/158/ check this fiddle

Comment: do you dont see that 1,2,3 is on same line as button? I want display it on different line

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C2K9Z/159/

Comment: you need to show numbers in different line and buttons in different line

Comment: yes, exactly ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<h4><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i> 2</h4>
<ul id="filter-version" class="filter multiple-select term-list">
    <li data-id="3">
        <a href="#">a</a>
    </li>
    <li data-id="1">
        <a href="#">b</a>
    </li>
    <li data-id="2">
        <a href="#">c</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm more-less" style="float:right">Więcej</button>

<span class="btn btn-default btn-sm start-filter" data-filter="version" style="float:right">Pokaż</span><br/>
```